# Open a locked (broken) washing machine

Tags: washing-machine

We have a washing machine that is kept outside, and we forgot to cover it so it got rained on and when we started it we heard a pop and smoke came out, and the circuit breaker went off. And now the clothes are trapped inside! :)

I don't care to pay any money to fix the machine right now, as I bought it second-hand for less than the cost of hiring a technician. My only concern is to get our clothes out now.

How do I open this washing machine door (hopefully in the least destructive way?)
I opened up the top, and tried jiggling the lock from both sides.

The machine model is Spectra WM2605 (made in italy), but the manual cannot be found online anywhere.

[image: inside showing lock]

Comment: Is there an obvious wire that comes out of the lock that you might be able to apply voltage to?  That lock is probably electro-mechanically operated.

Comment: Some machines have a mechanical lock release mechanism... might be worth checking if yours has or not.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yes, in theory yes, how difficult is that to do?

Comment: @John Already checked. Definitely does not have one

Answer (score 1):

Because your electronics are probably fried you can just pry it open.

The cost of replacing the electronics will probably *be more then it is worth* to fix and you can get a used one cheaper.

**But if want to make sure you can pay to have an appliance repair person come out and tell you what it would cost to repair.**

The latch in most cases is just a plastic piece that is being held by the electronic mechanism.

I would just pry and break the plastic locking mechanism.

A big crowbar would do the job.

Comment: Pry it off from the inside?

Comment: Obviously I can just break the door, but I prefer to do this in the least destructive way, so that maybe I can fix it later.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to find this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/-65_eoT6zuk) from how-2-repair.com.  I normally don't like to post links to videos as answers, but this covers a few excellent and easy ways to pop the door open.

To summarize, the catch on the door is spring loaded on some washers, so if you can wrap a string or wire around the latch and pull it, the door will pop open.

In some cases, the latch isn't accessible, so they show how to disassemble the latch from the inside, and it looks very much like the latch in your picture.